# digest error in angular for window.location.assign(url) in IE

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

I'm using angular js and i get following error whenever i'm trying to change window location url using window.location.assign(url). This happens only in IE
Here is the error which i get:

```
10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [["fn: function $locationWatch() {\n      var oldUrl = $browser.url();\n      var currentReplace = $location.$$replace;\n\n      if (!changeCounter || oldUrl != $location.absUrl()) {\n        changeCounter++;\n        $rootScope.$evalAsync(function() {\n          if ($rootScope.$broadcast('$locationChangeStart', $location.absUrl(), oldUrl).\n              defaultPrevented) {\n            $location.$$parse(oldUrl);\n          } else {\n            $browser.url($location.absUrl(), currentReplace);\n            afterLocationChange(oldUrl);\n          }\n        });\n      }\n      $location.$$replace = false;\n\n      return changeCounter;\n    }; newVal: 9; oldVal: 8","fn: function ngModelWatch() {\n    var value = ngModelGet($scope);\n\n    // if scop
```

My JS code from which call is made:

```
$scope.onRowClick = function(selected, row, $event) {       
        if(selected){
            window.location.assign("/lora/#/origination/" + row.loanRequestNo); 
        }
    };
```

my router js.

```
var app = angular.module('loraApp', []);

app.config([ '$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/dashboard', {
        templateUrl : 'app/html/dashboard.html'
    }).when('/origination', {
        templateUrl : 'app/html/origination/origination.html' , controller: 'OriginationCtrl'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo : '/dashboard'
    });
} ]);
```

I'm trying to navigate from /dashboard to /origination. But this happens also when I try to navigate from /origination to /origination. basically this happens whenever my code encounters window.location.url

Comment: Are you attempting to navigate to a route defined in your angular SPA? or to another route on your server?

Comment: updated question with routing details

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will want to inject `$location` into your controller, and then set the path using `$location`

```
$location.url('/organization/' + row.loanRequestNo);
```

[$location documenation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24location)

**EDIT** based upon the routes you have defined you are not going to receive the parameter row.loanRequestNo. you will need to update that route to this:

```
/organization/:loadRequestNo
```

And capture it on the destination controller via [$routeParams](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/%24routeParams)

**EDIT** [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ud9H2/1/)

Comment: $location.url is just appending its parameter to window url. i want complete path to change. i tried using various options of $location like  .host() , .port(), .path(), .url(). I want to change window url from 'http://localhost.ms.com:20137/lora/#/dashboard' to 'http://localhost.ms.com:20137/lora/#/origination/1121'

Comment: @Pranalee I created a fiddle showing it working using $location.path, including capturing parameters

Comment: Thanks. My mistake was that  i was passing  $location.url("/contextroot/#/origination/") instead of  $location.url("/origination/"). Argument to $location must match to values defined in router